# SQL Server on Ubuntu - backups best practices?

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server

I've installed MS SQL Express on an Ubuntu VPS, after moving from a shared hosting windows plan for a low traffic .net core site.

What is the best practices to backup the databases? I'm currently doing this manually through SMSS which then gets saved to /var/opt/mssql/data.

How can I automate the backup processes? I'd like some daily / weekly process and then also be able to trigger a manual backup just before deploying a release or something.

Which file location on the server should the backups live?

My host provides Acronis Backup I believe.

Database size is super small at the moment ~10 MB, but I expect it will grow over time.

Comment: you can install sqlcmd command line utility (as well as other command line tools in mssql-tools package) and use it for backup databases on scheduler.

Comment: I prefer to use AutoMySQLBackup script https://sqlbak.com/blog/how-to-automate-mysql-database-backups-in-linux#automysqlbackup

Comment: If you want to backup SQL via FTP here is another good script: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-mysql-nas-ftp-backup-script/